# Minimizing the lenght and the energy

Tags: geometry, optimization, classical-mechanics, optimal-control

The optimal control problem
$$
J(u) = \min \int_0^T \sqrt{u_1^2+u_2^2} dt
$$
$$
\dot q = f(q,u),\quad q(0)=a\quad q(T)=b
$$

($q\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $u\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $T$ is fixed and $f$ is smooth)

is equivalent to the optimal control problem
$$
\tilde J(u) =\min \int_0^T (u_1^2+u_2^2) dt
$$
$$
\dot q = f(q,u),\quad q(0)=a\quad q(T)=b
$$
.

In which sense these problems are equivalent ? they have the same cost function : $J(u) = \tilde J(u)$ ? 
How to prove this equivalence (if you have a reference)?

If a constraint is added on the control like $|u|\le 1$ then the equivalence doesn't hold ?

Comment: eh both integrals are continuously increasing function of $\Vert u \Vert_2$. So both problems are equivalent to finding u with least l2 norm that satisfies your weird constraint (q(0) = a and b lol?). If one more constraint is added on l1 norm of u I really don't see how they are not still equivalent.

Comment: I join this document, you just have to look at the beginning of page 3 where they say that minimizing the length is equivalent to minimizing the energy with respect to the $\bf Maupertuis's\; principle$. And they say in the case where the norm of $u$ is L^1, this principle doesn't hold. Can anyone have good reference about the Maupertuis's principle ?
http://caillau.perso.math.cnrs.fr/research/ifip-05-proc.pdf